# Javascript "Expected ']'"

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I figure i've just been staring at my screen too long today - I can't find the error here. I've got a jQuery template and i'm using KnockoutJS's foreach on it.  Inside i have a button and i'm trying to call a function onclick and pass in an iteration value. Here's the snippet from the template. The only thing that i can think would be wrong is something about my jQuery template syntax, tho it's working elsewhere
`<button onclick="newTabify(${$data})">Chat</button>`

My template looks like this...(the button's inside, along with a bunch of other stuff)

```
 <div data-bind='template: {name: "contactTemplate", foreach:contacts}' id="contactList"></div>
<script id='contactTemplate' type='text/html'>
 ... 
</script>
```

The newTabify function looks like:

```
 function newTabify(contact) {
        tabify($.inArray(contact, viewModel.contacts()));
    }
```

What's extremeley odd here is the error.

```
SCRIPT1007: Expected ']' 
default.html, line 1 character 19
```

Line 1 is my `<head>` tag!!

If you need anymore markup just lemme know. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my contact template. The funny thing is there's not a thing wrong with any of it except for the click event on the button when i try to add the line as shown above. But here's the rest anyways.

```
{{if $data.jid() != viewModel.jid() }}
    <div class="wrapper" onclick="wrapperClick(this)">
    <div style="padding-bottom:4px">
    <img src=images/${$data.avail}.png> ${ $data.name } <img class="avatar" src=images/${$data.img}><br> <span class="status">${$data.status }</span>
                </div>
        <a href="mailto:${$data.jid}" >${$data.jid}</a> | <button onclick="newTabify(${$data})">Chat</button> | <button onclick="event.stopPropagation();">Call</button>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
```

EDIT 2: $data a contact object; i'm looping through contacts (an observable array of contact objects) and sucessfully pulling all the values out of contact, etc. Here's my contact:

```
function contact(name, status, avail, jid, img, convIndex){
    return {
    name : ko.observable(name),
    status : ko.observable(status),
    avail : ko.observable(avail), 
    img : ko.observable(img),
    jid : ko.observable(jid),
    convIndex: ko.observable(convIndex)
    };
```

}

So technically $data should be a instanct of the above.

Comment: can you include your template? the `contactTemplate` ?

Comment: Interestingly enough, i could write ${$data} to the screen without an error. Only when i try to pass it in as an argument do i get an error.

Comment: have you tried using `newTabify($data)` ? I am slightly lost here but why are you using double $ (e.g. ${$name}) to access the variable? I never saw that anywhere before?

Comment: the double $ is because of jQuery templates - a template is contained inside a scriptblock which contains html, and to insert code you use ${ (or ${{ for syntax) and since $data is variable in code, i have to use ${ to get to it.

Comment: @Thomas: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't guarantee that this is your only problem, but this line is not going to give you what you are expecting:

```
<button onclick="newTabify(${$data})">Chat</button>
```

Doing ${$data} is going to give you the .toString() of your object.  For your object it will look like:

```
[object Object]
```

So, this would not be valid syntax.

Since, you are using Knockout you can instead do something like this (even inside of a template) and it will pass the actual object properly:

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { newTabify($data); }">Chat</button>
```

Comment: Man, you ROCK. That's the second knockout question you've answered within an hour of my asking. Keep it up.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you run [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) against your code. It should point you in the right direction.

Comment: JSLint doesn't recognize jQuery templates or KnockoutJS, so this won't work.

Comment: @Thomas did not know that, thanks for setting me straight. Looks like you may already have your answer above as well.