# VM[number] file causes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, parsing

I have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` from the file `VM3154:1`.

 The error appears after I login with a Parse user.
I try to locate the file in my server and I cannot find this file. This file has only one line of code:

```
[object Object]
```

Anybody knows what is this file? What does it do?

There is an increment for the number every time I log in using Parse User function.

My web uses jQuery, AngularJS, Parse and Bootstrap.

Comment: where do you see this error: in browser console or in your application logs?

Comment: I see this in the browser console.

Comment: can you paste the full console error?

Comment: [DATETIME] Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier VM3154:1

Comment: can you post here the list of file sincluded in this page that thorws the exception?

Comment: The errors change from time to time with different files.
When I wrote the question, it was VM3154, now it is VM16148.

Comment: Only one file throws the exception. And the file names are changed. Now its VM16253

Comment: There is an increment every time I log in using Parse User function.

Comment: Without any piece of code, I can only suggest to comment out one by on efiles you have included in this page and see when this error will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

This can occur when a callback function is expected, but the code is returning an object instead. My specific case was a `new` before the `function` passed to `setTimeout`, and I only figured it out thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31502293 (Firefox edition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218837)

> `setTimeout` expects the first parameter to be a function

NOTE: Sometimes this error occurs when a missing quote in JSON causes a comma to be treated as part of the preceding string, eg: `['test1,'test2']`.

Example.html to reproduce:

```
<script>
setTimeout(new function() { document.write('test') },0);
</script>
```

Instead of clicking the `VM61:1` (the number auto-increments) link on the right-hand side, click the gray drop-down arrow/icon on the lef-hand side between the error icon and the words `Uncaught SyntaxError` to show the call stack and click the first link in the list (see screencast below).

This will jump one frame up the callstack and usually highlight the entire line where the error occurred. It will not pinpoint the exact location of the error but review here carefully for anything that could be returning an object when a callback function is expected.

[image: Screencast: Chrome Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier VM]

Remove the `new` and the error goes away!

PS. This error appeared in Internet Explorer 10 (unless it is running in Compatability Mode) as

```
SCRIPT1007: Expected ']'
example.html, line 1 character 9
```

And in Firefox 56 as

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list[Learn More]  example.html:2:8
```

Comment: Linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844913 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163955 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875776 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856004 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215185

Comment: Thanks for to GIF! It helped me.