# SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox-gl.js map with markers within a vue component. At the end of a mapdrag a list is made of all markers in the viewport (with a setTimeout to avoid performance issues with many markers). Everything works as expected but I get a error at the end of a drag/moveend:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

No further details..., the error refers e.g. to VM9336 which contains:

```
[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement]
```

The number of [object HTMLDivElement] 's matches the number of markers in viewport.

The error seems to emerge from this function of mapbox-gl.js:

```
Actor.prototype.receive = function(t) {
                var e, a = this, r = t.data, s = r.id;
                if (!r.targetMapId || this.mapId === r.targetMapId) {
                    var i = function(t, e, r) {
                        a.target.postMessage({
                            sourceMapId: a.mapId,
                            type: "<response>",
                            id: String(s),
                            error: t ? String(t) : null,
                            data: e
                        }, r)
                    };
                    if ("<response>" === r.type)
                        e = this.callbacks[r.id],
                        delete this.callbacks[r.id],
                        e && e(r.error || null, r.data);
                    else if ("undefined" != typeof r.id && this.parent[r.type])
                        this.parent[r.type](r.sourceMapId, r.data, i);
                    else if ("undefined" != typeof r.id && this.parent.getWorkerSource) {
                        var p = r.type.split(".")
                          , d = this.parent.getWorkerSource(r.sourceMapId, p[0]);
                        d[p[1]](r.data, i)
                    } else
                        this.parent[r.type](r.data)
                }
            }
```

As I am pretty much lost..., any idea?

EDIT: in Firefox (instead of Chrome) I get following errormessage:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list  0.821efde866de69447c4f.js%20line%20491%20%3E%20eval:119:8
```

but when clicking on the code-link Firefox does not seem to be able to read the code...

Comment: Can you post the code that's triggering the error?

Comment: Well that's not clear... it is not mentioned in the error.

Comment: I think you're going to need to do a bit more investigation at your end to find what's triggering the error. Or maybe you could post a link to a site showing the problem.